# How to choose a <select> option value automatically from an URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

I have 2 step form and I'm passing the first name in the URL from step 1 to step 2, but I'm not sure how to do the same thing for a `select` field. As an example I have this:

In the URL:

> ?firstname=Bob

Form Field:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_GET['firstname']; ?>" required>
```

There is a variable passing in the URL for the select field which is:

> &colortype=Black+and+White

But the Select options look like this:

```
<label for="colortype">Colors...</label>
<select id="colortype" name="colortype">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select an option</option>
    <option value="Purple and Yellow">Purple and Yellow</option>
    <option value="Red and Blue">Red and Blue</option>
    <option value="Black and White">Black and White</option>
</select>
```

I have tried adding the option:

```
<option value="<?php echo $_GET['colortype']; ?>">
<?php echo $_GET['colortype']; ?>
</option>
```

But no luck. Is there a way to automatically select the `colortype` that comes through the URL?

Comment: Put those values in an array and do a for to make the options, comparing each one to value on $_GET to set the selected one.

Comment: add selected attribute when you select value match with value from GET['colortype']

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<label for="colortype">Colors...</label>
<select id="colortype" name="colortype">
<option <?php if ($_GET['colortype'] == '' ) echo 'selected' ; ?>  value="" disabled hidden>Select an option</option>
<option <?php if ($_GET['colortype'] == 'Purple and Yellow' ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="Purple and Yellow">Purple and Yellow</option>
<option <?php if ($_GET['colortype'] == 'Red and Blue' ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="Red and Blue">Red and Blue</option>
<option <?php if ($_GET['colortype'] == 'Black and White' ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="Black and White">Black and White</option>
</select>
```

Comment: On first run (no arguments given in url) it'll have some undefined index warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="colortype">Colors...</label>
<select id="colortype" name="colortype">
<?php $color = $_GET['colortype']; ?>
<option <?php if ($color == '' ) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="" >Select an option</option>
<option <?php if ($color == 'Purple and Yellow' ) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Purple and Yellow" >Select an option</option>
<option <?php if ($color == 'Red and Blue' ) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Red and Blue" >Select an option</option>
<option <?php if ($color == 'Black and White' ) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="Black and White" >Select an option</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

Colors...

```
<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select an option</option>
<option value="1">Purple and Yellow</option>
<option value="2">Red and Blue</option>
<option value="3">Black and White</option>
```

value="Black and White">Black and White